# Connection refused trying to connect via ingress interface

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Using Calico as CNI and CRI-O. DNS settings properly configured. Installed NGINX ingress controller via official documentation page of NGINX using helm. Set `replicaset` to 2 when installing.

After that used this file for creating 3 objects: `Deployment`, `Service` for exposing web server and `Ingress`.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: test-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-service-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-service-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx 
        name: test-nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: nginx-service
spec:
   type: ClusterIP
   selector:
      app: nginx-service-pod
   ports:
      - port: 80
        targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: k8s.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /test
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx-service
            port:
              number: 80
...
```

Tried to test deployment service by curling it and it is working correct:

```
# curl http://10.103.88.163
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I'm trying to curl Ingress getting error:

```
# curl http://k8s.example.com/test
curl: (7) Failed to connect to k8s.example.com port 80: Connection refused
```

Why this is happening? Because as I see there is no misconfig in the objects configuration.

Comment: What ingress controller are you using? How did you expose it to the internet? what IP did you point your hostname to?

Comment: Does the hostname k8s.example.com resolve to actual IP of nginx ingress controller node? What is the type of Service of nginx-ingress-controller? If it's NodePort  then you need to connect to NodePort port number instead of 80.

Comment: Hi, @whites11 I'm using NGINX controller downloaded and installed from official NGINX documentations. k8s cluster on-premise. Trying to connect on the LAN.

k8s.example.com - 10.0.0.50 IP DNS A Record created. 10.0.0.50 is the master node of the cluster and k8s.example.com is fqdn of the master node.

Comment: @vasili-angapov Yes, it's resolving. I have already DNS A Record. nginx-ingress-controller is LoadBalancer type. I need to connect to my /test ingress path (pointing to my internal ClusterIP service of web server).

Comment: are you sure nginx ingress runs on master node? I think you need to connect to NodePort port of nginx-ingress controller instead of 80.

Comment: @vasili-angapov  curl http://k8s.example.com:30540
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.5</center>
</body>
</html>

I need connect to http://k8s.example.com/test which is pointing to internal ClusterIP service of web server.

Comment: curl k8s.example.com:30540/test

Comment: @VasiliAngapov curl k8s.example.com:30540/test
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.21.5</center>
</body>
</html>

Must be Welcome to nginx not 404 error.

Comment: Check nginx-ingress logs. Also Ingress and Service must be in the same namespace.

Comment: @VasiliAngapov it is all in default namespace.

In the logs nothing special except:
2022/01/11 06:15:53 [notice] 14#14: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 17
2022/01/11 06:15:53 [notice] 14#14: worker process 16 exited with code 0
2022/01/11 06:15:53 [notice] 14#14: worker process 17 exited with code 0
2022/01/11 06:15:53 [notice] 14#14: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2022/01/11 06:15:53 [notice] 14#14: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 18
2022/01/11 06:15:53 [notice] 14#14: worker process 18 exited with code 0
2022/01/11 06:15:53 [notice] 14#14: signal 29 (SIGIO) received

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak

COMPONENT                 CURRENT   TARGET
kube-apiserver            v1.22.4   v1.22.5
kube-controller-manager   v1.22.4   v1.22.5
kube-scheduler            v1.22.4   v1.22.5
kube-proxy                v1.22.4   v1.22.5
CoreDNS                   v1.8.4    v1.8.4
etcd                      3.5.0-0   3.5.0-0

Installation on VM machines on VMware. Cluster installed using kubeadm tool. Same thing happening on the work test cluster and home test cluster.

Comment: Did the request `curl http://k8s.example.com` (without `/test` part) works for you?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak no, connection refused.

Comment: Are you sure, that your ingress port is open?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak if you are asking about port 80 then in the netstat nothing is listening on it. Why?

Comment: Check [this answer on github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4799#issuecomment-560406420) and let me know if it works.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak hostNetwork: true must be in which deployment? Deployment of nginx ingress controller?

Comment: Try add this to the ingress yaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was missing metallb for on-premise infrastructure. Because I tried to access service with default 443/80 port.

Answer (score 3):

This problem should be resolved by adding

```
spec: 
  template:
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
```

to the ingress controller yaml manifest. For more please check [this github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4799) and [this answer](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4799#issuecomment-560406420).